# How to open excel, doc from ms-word or ms-excel in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, excel, ms-word, ms-office

[image]

In my application I download doc and excel files and I want user to open them from MS Word, MS Excel application available for iPad. I don't want these files to be opened in web view but wants to open in MS word or excel in the same way like after long press in my Mail app I get option to open document from different application.

I have attached the screenshot of what I want to achieve. 
Please let me know the way I can achieve it.

Comment: Use `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

Comment: check this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-previewing-and-opening-documents--mobile-15130) for UIDocumentInteractionController example.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the QuickLook Framework Available for iOS. [Here](http://kratinmobile.com/blog/index.php/document-preview-in-ios-with-quick-look-framework/) is a great tutorial for that